# How do you use commas when referring to a person and yourself in a sentence while naming the person?

Tags: punctuation

The sentence is:

> My wife, Anne, and I are going to the dentist this afternoon.

I am unsure with this because it sounds like the sentence is talking about 3 different persons: (1) Wife (2) Anne (3) I. But what I really intend for it is that  it is talking about only 2 different persons. (1) Wife whose name is Anne (2) I.

Is the use of the commas in the sentence correct?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/416590/42179 However, there is a difference: usually there is only one wife, and more than one friend. So, 'wife' and 'friend' can be comma-treated differently as explained over there.

Comment: I suppose you could write: My wife, Anne; and I are [...] as suggested by https://english.stackexchange.com/a/141285/42179

Comment: @Weoathtocreation thank you for the very helpful links.

Comment: There are ways to clarify beyond any doubt. [A] My wife (Anne) and I ... / My wife Anne and I ... [zero punctuation around parentheticals (here a renaming appositive) is not unacceptable in cases where smooth-runningness is fine and clarity not compromised] //// My wife, and Anne, and I ... /  Anne, and my wife and I ... [this latter hints that there are two parties, {Anne}, and {my wife and I}].